# Query related to designing sharepoint page online

Tags: image, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to create a sharepoint page where I need to add an image (let's call it imagefile.jpg). This image resides in a folder in sharepoint document library. The requirement is that if the original image gets replaced by a new image (the name remains same i.e. imagefile.jpg), then the new image should show on the sharepoint page instead of the old image. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think SPO *is* supposed to do what you want automatically. After you upload a new version of the image, wait a few minutes for all of Microsoft's mirrored SPO servers to catch up with each other, and refresh the page that contains the image, then drink coffee and refresh again, and it might work as you hoped.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is Image webpart in Sharepoint Online does not load the new image on page refresh. A bit weird!

Answer (score 0):

All SharePoint files hosted in SharePoint site are inside two ways cache management: a SharePoint and browser cache management; then, to see the update, open the image URL at the browser, and make Ctrl + F5 on this, and reload the candidate page.

It's possible what you´ll need to notify the user area that consumes this candidate page.